# Running PSPLinux [uClinux] on PSP 3004

Tags: linux

uClinux is currently available on PSP, and it's considered "working". Unfortunately i can't start it on my 3004 model (firmaware 6.20). PSP version of linux is **not** a replacement for system, but it's developed as a program to be run. The error message says that the data is corrupted. I tried with different download sources.
How can i run it?

Comment: Do you have a custom firmware?

Comment: @Anonymous no. Is there any way to get it w/o magic memory stick and pandora battery?

Answer (score 0):

You need CFW, or LCFW, at the very least.

I recommend PRO CFW.

I believe the latest release of PRO is PRO-C2. It's light custom firmware that goes away if you do a full shutdown (not suspension). The "Recovery" or "Fast Recovery" must be ran each time you boot up.

https://code.google.com/p/procfw/wiki/Installation